# Linux Debian screen brightness stuck on high on macbook air

Tags: linux

The screen brightness on my macbook air either goes to completely dim or one of the top three brightnesses options. The buttons F1 and F2 work fine and it does indicate the brightness is changing when I press the buttons, but the actual brightness does not change.

I found a solution online, which works fine until I close the laptop and reopen it, it just goes back to not working.

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor splash quiet"
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Have you found a solution yet? I haven't changed my grub settings, and I have the same behavior: it works fine after a boot, but then it breaks after I close the lid.

Comment: I went into /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight and tried echoing values into "brightness".

Using 2228 or higher seems to give full brightness.
Using 2227 yields a wierd blinking effect.
Using 2226 also yields the blinking effect, but a lot darker.
Finally, 2225 and lower gives complete darkness.

Comment: So, I occasionally also get this weird blinking effect.

Comment: I believe I had to download the correct driver for my computer. I don't remember exactly what fixed it.