# Screen brightness on Debian after sleep/hibernate on Macbook with Intel graphics card

Tags: debian, macintosh, intel-graphics, brightness

I'm having trouble with the screen brightness on my Macbook.

After (re)booting, it works fine, but after closing and re-opening the lid, the screen is either really bright (on the top 3 brightness settings when adjusting using the brightness keys), or completely black (anything under those top 3 settings).

I have an Intel graphics card.

I know about this post [Linux Debian screen brightness stuck on high on macbook air](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228912/180064), but the solution proposed there seems to have no effect at all. The result that is supposed to happen from the proposed kernel option seems to be the default behavior in my case. (There appears to have been a kernel update affecting this issue.)

When I run `systemctl suspend` and wake the laptop immediately, the problem behavior is not exhibited. However, sometimes, it gets stuck on the dark screen for a longer while, so it's probably doing something more than just suspend mode (hibernation?), and after that the problem behavior starts and won't stop until I reboot.

(Edit: More info)

I went into /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight and tried echoing values into "brightness":

- Using 2228 or higher seems to give full brightness.
- Using 2227 yields a wierd blinking effect.
- Using 2226 also yields the blinking effect, but a lot darker.
- Finally, 2225 and lower gives complete darkness.

What are my options?

EDIT: Found these suspicious messages in dmesg:

EDIT 2: These messages might not be related, ad I now have the behavior without those messages. I also installed a backported version of the kernel (4.1 I think), but I booted back into 3.16 since the wifi didn't work there.

```
    ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1390.187272] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2922 at /build/linux-lqALYs/linux-3.16.7-ckt25/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c:5992 intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]()
[ 1390.187276] Modules linked in: xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables binfmt_misc nf_nat nf_conntrack bridge stp llc aufs(C) bnep pci_stub vboxpci(O) vboxnetadp(O) cpufreq_conservative vboxnetflt(O) cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_userspace cpufreq_stats vboxdrv(O) nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd fscache sunrpc ecb btusb snd_hda_codec_hdmi bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc hid_generic efi_pstore usb_storage hid_apple joydev usbhid hid bcm5974 iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp intel_rapl coretemp kvm_intel kvm crc32_pclmul evdev applesmc input_polldev aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic efivars pcspkr i915
[ 1390.187367]  i2c_i801 lpc_ich drm_kms_helper mfd_core snd_hda_intel drm snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec i2c_algo_bit snd_hwdep i2c_core snd_pcm snd_timer mei_me apple_bl snd shpchp mei soundcore sbs sbshc battery video ac button processor thermal_sys wl(PO) cfg80211 rfkill fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 sg sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common ahci libahci libata xhci_hcd crc32c_intel scsi_mod usbcore usb_common
[ 1390.187448] CPU: 0 PID: 2922 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        WC O  3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2
[ 1390.187452] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookAir6,2/Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5, BIOS MBA61.88Z.0099.B22.1602221559 02/22/2016
[ 1390.187456]  0000000000000000 ffffffff8150e835 0000000000000000 0000000000000009
[ 1390.187464]  ffffffff810677f7 ffff8802657e002c ffff8802657e0000 ffff8802657e0000
[ 1390.187471]  000000000000000b ffff8802657e8520 ffffffffa09c7067 ffff880264d44800
[ 1390.187478] Call Trace:
[ 1390.187493]  [<ffffffff8150e835>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
[ 1390.187502]  [<ffffffff810677f7>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x77/0x90
[ 1390.187531]  [<ffffffffa09c7067>] ? intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]
[ 1390.187555]  [<ffffffffa0a29713>] ? intel_dp_detect+0xa3/0x310 [i915]
[ 1390.187568]  [<ffffffffa094a952>] ? drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x272/0x370 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 1390.187584]  [<ffffffffa098cd7d>] ? drm_mode_getconnector+0x3dd/0x450 [drm]
[ 1390.187590]  [<ffffffff8109fa40>] ? check_preempt_wakeup+0x120/0x1d0
[ 1390.187603]  [<ffffffffa097e8b7>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1c7/0x5b0 [drm]
[ 1390.187612]  [<ffffffff811bacdf>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4b0
[ 1390.187618]  [<ffffffff814076de>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x3e/0x80
[ 1390.187622]  [<ffffffff811baf41>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
[ 1390.187628]  [<ffffffff81514a0d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
[ 1390.187631] ---[ end trace 93ce5c17abaf8e25 ]---
[ 1390.187647] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1390.187664] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2922 at /build/linux-lqALYs/linux-3.16.7-ckt25/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c:5992 intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]()
[ 1390.187666] Modules linked in: xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables binfmt_misc nf_nat nf_conntrack bridge stp llc aufs(C) bnep pci_stub vboxpci(O) vboxnetadp(O) cpufreq_conservative vboxnetflt(O) cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_userspace cpufreq_stats vboxdrv(O) nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd fscache sunrpc ecb btusb snd_hda_codec_hdmi bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc hid_generic efi_pstore usb_storage hid_apple joydev usbhid hid bcm5974 iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp intel_rapl coretemp kvm_intel kvm crc32_pclmul evdev applesmc input_polldev aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic efivars pcspkr i915
[ 1390.187717]  i2c_i801 lpc_ich drm_kms_helper mfd_core snd_hda_intel drm snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec i2c_algo_bit snd_hwdep i2c_core snd_pcm snd_timer mei_me apple_bl snd shpchp mei soundcore sbs sbshc battery video ac button processor thermal_sys wl(PO) cfg80211 rfkill fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 sg sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common ahci libahci libata xhci_hcd crc32c_intel scsi_mod usbcore usb_common
[ 1390.187758] CPU: 0 PID: 2922 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        WC O  3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2
[ 1390.187761] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookAir6,2/Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5, BIOS MBA61.88Z.0099.B22.1602221559 02/22/2016
[ 1390.187762]  0000000000000000 ffffffff8150e835 0000000000000000 0000000000000009
[ 1390.187766]  ffffffff810677f7 ffff8802657e002c ffff8802655ffc00 ffff8802657e0000
[ 1390.187770]  000000000000000b ffff8802657e8520 ffffffffa09c7067 ffff8802655ffc00
[ 1390.187774] Call Trace:
[ 1390.187780]  [<ffffffff8150e835>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
[ 1390.187785]  [<ffffffff810677f7>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x77/0x90
[ 1390.187803]  [<ffffffffa09c7067>] ? intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]
[ 1390.187825]  [<ffffffffa0a2575c>] ? intel_dp_get_modes+0x6c/0x100 [i915]
[ 1390.187837]  [<ffffffffa094a966>] ? drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x286/0x370 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 1390.187851]  [<ffffffffa098cd7d>] ? drm_mode_getconnector+0x3dd/0x450 [drm]
[ 1390.187856]  [<ffffffff8109fa40>] ? check_preempt_wakeup+0x120/0x1d0
[ 1390.187868]  [<ffffffffa097e8b7>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1c7/0x5b0 [drm]
[ 1390.187875]  [<ffffffff811bacdf>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4b0
[ 1390.187880]  [<ffffffff814076de>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x3e/0x80
[ 1390.187884]  [<ffffffff811baf41>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
[ 1390.187889]  [<ffffffff81514a0d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
[ 1390.187892] ---[ end trace 93ce5c17abaf8e26 ]---
[ 1390.733474] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1390.733537] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2922 at /build/linux-lqALYs/linux-3.16.7-ckt25/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c:5992 intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]()
[ 1390.733542] Modules linked in: xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables binfmt_misc nf_nat nf_conntrack bridge stp llc aufs(C) bnep pci_stub vboxpci(O) vboxnetadp(O) cpufreq_conservative vboxnetflt(O) cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_userspace cpufreq_stats vboxdrv(O) nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd fscache sunrpc ecb btusb snd_hda_codec_hdmi bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc hid_generic efi_pstore usb_storage hid_apple joydev usbhid hid bcm5974 iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp intel_rapl coretemp kvm_intel kvm crc32_pclmul evdev applesmc input_polldev aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic efivars pcspkr i915
[ 1390.733653]  i2c_i801 lpc_ich drm_kms_helper mfd_core snd_hda_intel drm snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec i2c_algo_bit snd_hwdep i2c_core snd_pcm snd_timer mei_me apple_bl snd shpchp mei soundcore sbs sbshc battery video ac button processor thermal_sys wl(PO) cfg80211 rfkill fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 sg sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common ahci libahci libata xhci_hcd crc32c_intel scsi_mod usbcore usb_common
[ 1390.733749] CPU: 0 PID: 2922 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        WC O  3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2
[ 1390.733754] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookAir6,2/Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5, BIOS MBA61.88Z.0099.B22.1602221559 02/22/2016
[ 1390.733759]  0000000000000000 ffffffff8150e835 0000000000000000 0000000000000009
[ 1390.733768]  ffffffff810677f7 ffff8802657e002c ffff8802657e0000 ffff8802657e0000
[ 1390.733776]  000000000000000b ffff8802657e8520 ffffffffa09c7067 ffff880264d44800
[ 1390.733785] Call Trace:
[ 1390.733802]  [<ffffffff8150e835>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
[ 1390.733813]  [<ffffffff810677f7>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x77/0x90
[ 1390.733846]  [<ffffffffa09c7067>] ? intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]
[ 1390.733884]  [<ffffffffa0a29713>] ? intel_dp_detect+0xa3/0x310 [i915]
[ 1390.733904]  [<ffffffffa094a952>] ? drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x272/0x370 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 1390.733930]  [<ffffffffa098cd7d>] ? drm_mode_getconnector+0x3dd/0x450 [drm]
[ 1390.733940]  [<ffffffff811bb8e0>] ? poll_select_copy_remaining+0x140/0x140
[ 1390.733962]  [<ffffffffa097e8b7>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1c7/0x5b0 [drm]
[ 1390.733974]  [<ffffffff8108ae2d>] ? __hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x1cd/0x390
[ 1390.733982]  [<ffffffff811bacdf>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4b0
[ 1390.733993]  [<ffffffff814076de>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x3e/0x80
[ 1390.734000]  [<ffffffff811baf41>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
[ 1390.734010]  [<ffffffff81514a0d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
[ 1390.734016] ---[ end trace 93ce5c17abaf8e27 ]---
[ 1390.734040] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1390.734070] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2922 at /build/linux-lqALYs/linux-3.16.7-ckt25/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c:5992 intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]()
[ 1390.734073] Modules linked in: xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables binfmt_misc nf_nat nf_conntrack bridge stp llc aufs(C) bnep pci_stub vboxpci(O) vboxnetadp(O) cpufreq_conservative vboxnetflt(O) cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_userspace cpufreq_stats vboxdrv(O) nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd fscache sunrpc ecb btusb snd_hda_codec_hdmi bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc hid_generic efi_pstore usb_storage hid_apple joydev usbhid hid bcm5974 iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp intel_rapl coretemp kvm_intel kvm crc32_pclmul evdev applesmc input_polldev aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic efivars pcspkr i915
[ 1390.734180]  i2c_i801 lpc_ich drm_kms_helper mfd_core snd_hda_intel drm snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec i2c_algo_bit snd_hwdep i2c_core snd_pcm snd_timer mei_me apple_bl snd shpchp mei soundcore sbs sbshc battery video ac button processor thermal_sys wl(PO) cfg80211 rfkill fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 sg sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common ahci libahci libata xhci_hcd crc32c_intel scsi_mod usbcore usb_common
[ 1390.734262] CPU: 0 PID: 2922 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        WC O  3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2
[ 1390.734267] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookAir6,2/Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5, BIOS MBA61.88Z.0099.B22.1602221559 02/22/2016
[ 1390.734270]  0000000000000000 ffffffff8150e835 0000000000000000 0000000000000009
[ 1390.734278]  ffffffff810677f7 ffff8802657e002c ffff8802655ffc00 ffff8802657e0000
[ 1390.734287]  000000000000000b ffff8802657e8520 ffffffffa09c7067 ffff8802655ffc00
[ 1390.734295] Call Trace:
[ 1390.734305]  [<ffffffff8150e835>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
[ 1390.734314]  [<ffffffff810677f7>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x77/0x90
[ 1390.734344]  [<ffffffffa09c7067>] ? intel_display_power_put+0x127/0x150 [i915]
[ 1390.734381]  [<ffffffffa0a2575c>] ? intel_dp_get_modes+0x6c/0x100 [i915]
[ 1390.734399]  [<ffffffffa094a966>] ? drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x286/0x370 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 1390.734423]  [<ffffffffa098cd7d>] ? drm_mode_getconnector+0x3dd/0x450 [drm]
[ 1390.734432]  [<ffffffff811bb8e0>] ? poll_select_copy_remaining+0x140/0x140
[ 1390.734453]  [<ffffffffa097e8b7>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1c7/0x5b0 [drm]
[ 1390.734465]  [<ffffffff8108ae2d>] ? __hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x1cd/0x390
[ 1390.734473]  [<ffffffff811bacdf>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4b0
[ 1390.734482]  [<ffffffff814076de>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x3e/0x80
[ 1390.734489]  [<ffffffff811baf41>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
[ 1390.734499]  [<ffffffff81514a0d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
[ 1390.734504] ---[ end trace 93ce5c17abaf8e28 ]---
```

These messages appear every time I hit the brightness buttons, I'll reboot and see if they happen then.

Comment: It seems like this driver fixes things: https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl